# What is the .NET equivalent of JMX?

Tags: .net, monitoring, jmx

Is there a .NET equivalent for monitoring and management - similar to JMX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a JMX port to .net in Codeplex ([NetMX](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=NetMX)(dead link)).
And a related article in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/NetMX.aspx).

**UPD**: Latest live mirror of code on GitHub: [SzymonPobiega/NetMX](https://github.com/SzymonPobiega/NetMX)

Answer (score 7):

Try [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx), accessible through the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

There is Microsoft .Net Events but I'm afraid that you'll have to build the eventing into code.  Not that easy.  Wish that there was an attribute that you could add to "enable" monitoring of that specific method.