# Looking for a management like JMX for .net web applications

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, jmx

Is there any way to expose public static function for invocation to an outside tool? 
In java you can annotate the method and than you can invoke it via JMX.
I am talking about c# .NET web application.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the .NET equivalent of JMX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287152/what-is-the-net-equivalent-of-jmx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are nothing standard and built in. You can manually create a page and assign appropriate methods for button handlers manually, and provide all layout for input parameters. Less intuitive and usability way (and more dangerous) doing this via query string parameters, but I would not recommend this.